# Apache Spark SQL get values in dataframe from SQL query

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to get a string value from a SQL query with Apache Spark 2.2.0 as follows:

```
val result = spark.sql("SELECT AnswerText FROM datatable WHERE participantUUID='010A0550' AND assessmentNumber=0 AND Q_id_string = '1_Age'")

assertResult("23") {
  result.collect.head.getString(0)
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
next on empty iterator
java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator
```

I've tried `collectAsList` to return a row but not getting any joy from that, either. I simply want to return the actual value from the query in the DataFrame, not the column, row or field. In this case, the result is a string but it could also be an int - the age of the person = 23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens probably because query doesn't return any items. It would be better to use `headOption`

```
assertResult(Some("23")) {
  result.take(1).headOption.map(_.getAs[String]("AnswerText"))
}
```

or push it to SQL:

```
assertResult(1) {
  spark
    .sql("""SELECT AnswerText 
            FROM datatable 
            WHERE participantUUID='010A0550' AND 
                  assessmentNumber=0 AND
                  Q_id_string = '1_Age'""")
   .where($"AnswerText" === "23").count 
}
```